# ERROR 6 -- overflow issue

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is giving me an error code 6 overflow. When I click ok on the error the file opens. I use this same code to open other workbooks within this macro and they are fine. I move the file to my desto and it worked. BBut when trying to load it from a network loaction it fails. I make sure to clear my Variables before reusing them as well.

```
Dim xlWorkbook2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim FILEPATH As String

FILEPATH = "C:\\Daily Remit History Data\dailycashtran.xlsx"
Set xlWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH)
```

Comment: Why the double slash?

Comment: Other than the double slash in the FILEPATH there's nothing apparently wrong with this bit if code.  Even with the double slash or supposing that the Excel file you're opening might be corrupt, it's hard to see how an Overflow error could come out of this code.  Have you walked through it with the debugger and can you verify which line throws the error?

Comment: I walked through it a few times and its almost like its taking to long for the file to open. As soon as i click ok on the error the file opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the next line of code where i was doing a count on the number of cells if wasnt fininding the sheet name i have coded for.

count = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

I was opening another instance of EXCEL when the sheet opened. Once i saw the error of my ways and corrected the way i was opening the other workbook if fixed my issue.

Thanks